# Meteor DDP to ODATA

Tags: node.js, meteor, ddp

What do I need to do to replace the Server Side Mongo DB via the DDP to read/write to a set of ODATA services within the DDP.

Would it be best to create a DDP client that subscribes to the Meteor DDP or how should I go about implementing this.

Or is this a Node DDP Server?  If so, where are examples of DDP Servers?

Cheers

Comment: The DDP protocol was written by the Meteor team, for Meteor. I'm not sure what the status of 3rd party implementations are yet. [Here's the tentative (pre1) DDP specification](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/livedata/DDP.md).